# how to apply patterns on array enums in JSON schema

Tags: arrays, validation, jsonschema

I have a simple JSON schema that looks like so (and works)

```json
{
    "cols": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "age",
                "affiliation",
                ""
            ]
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

I would like the `enum` to be the values prescribed above + a decoration so that any of the following would be allowed

```json
"enum" = [
    "id",
    "lower(name)",
    "average(age)",
    "distinct(affiliation)",
    ""
]
```

In other words, for `cols`

- `cols=id` would be valid but no further decoration would be allowed around `id`
- `cols=name` and `cols=lower(name)` would be valid
- `cols=age` and `cols=average(age)` would be valid
- `cols=affiliation` and `cols=distinct(affiliation)` would be valid
- `cols=''` empty string would be valid

Specifying the decorations as patterns would be great so that they would be case-insensitive. For example, `cols=lower(name)` and `cols=LOWER(name)` would both be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your enumerated list in `enum` to a list of patterns:

```json
"items": [
  "type": "string",
  "anyOf": [
    { "pattern": "^cols\b...the rest of your pattern here...$" },
    { etc... }
  ]
]
```